# Validating Cells Within a Table While Editing

Tags: javascript, php, html, validation

Currently, I have a table where I can edit a row and save it after i am done editing. I want to be able to add validation so for example if the email cell doesn't include an email, then it will not save. I am wanting to display a dialog box displaying the error if you click save and a field hasn't been validated. How can I do this?

Here is what I need:

```
Buyer ID - numbers only
POC Name - text only
POC Email - email only
POC Phone - phone number only
```

Relative Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.edit').click(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var tds = $this.closest('tr').find('td').not('.mr_id').filter(function() {
            return $(this).find('.edit').length === 0;
        });
        if ($this.html() === 'Edit') {
            $this.html('Save');
            tds.prop('contenteditable', true);
        } else {
            $this.html('Edit');
            tds.prop('contenteditable', false);
        }
    });
    });
```

Relative HTML/PHP:

```
<?php
    foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $rows){
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td class="mr_id" contenteditable="false"><?php echo intval ($rows['MR_ID'])?></td>
        <td class="mr_name" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['MR_Name']?></td>
        <td class="buyer_id" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['Buyer_ID']?></td>
        <td class="poc_n" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['MR_POC_N']?></td>     
        <td class="poc_e" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['MR_POC_E']?></td>
        <td class="poc_p" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['MR_POC_P']?></td>
        <td><button class="edit" name="edit">Edit</button>
        <button class="delRow" name="delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)">Delete</button></td>
    </tr>
```

jQuery imports:

```
<head>
        <title>Stage Rebate Master HTML Table</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="html_master.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="html_master.js"></script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote you a little somthing to get you started, you'll need to add more `switch case` conditions (I handled `buyer_id` only) and add the dialog box (I used `#myDialogBox`) but I think you'll be okay :)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.edit').click(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var tds = $this.closest('tr').find('td').not('.mr_id').filter(function() {
        return $(this).find('.edit').length === 0;
    });
    if ($this.html() === 'Edit') {
        $this.html('Save');
        tds.prop('contenteditable', true);
    } else {
        var isValid = true;
        var errors = '';
        $('#myDialogBox').empty();
        tds.each(function(){
             var type = $(this).attr('class');
             var value = $(this).text();
             switch(type){
                 case "buyer_id":
                     if(!$.isNumeric(value)){
                          isValid = false;
                         errors += "numbers only in buyer id\n";
                      }
                     break;
             }
        })
        if(isValid){
            $this.html('Edit');
            tds.prop('contenteditable', false);
        }else{
            alert(errors);
        }
    }
});
});
```

Comment: Unless, there is something I am needing to add, it isn't seeming to work for me in my code.

Comment: Whenever I run it and the table comes up...if I edit the buyer ID so that the cell is blank or there are letters/words, it still lets me save it

Comment: Hmmm interesting....I added my jQuery import code into my post....do those seem correct?

Comment: you might have a conflict - since you use 2 jQuery files (local one and google's one) is there a reason for that?

Comment: there is no reason for it...let me take one out and see if that works

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124805/discussion-between-jameson-the-dog-and-rataiczak24).